# Stacking a lot of SVG images as layers issue

Tags: python, svg

So I would like to stack a lot of svg images on top of each other in Python.
I am using this to do so:

```
import svgutils.transform as st

template = st.fromfile('firstLayer.svg')
second_svg = st.fromfile('secondLayer.svg')
template.append(second_svg)
template.save('merged.svg')
```

It technically works.

Only problem is that for example in my first image (template) I have 9 classes (cls 1 - 9) and in the second I have 4 (cls 1 - 4).
The name of the classes doesn't change when stacking them so the images comes out weird because the style is mixing.
Does a solution that changes the classes name with respect to the existing SVG class name exists? for example If I stack the second layer on the first one the class names will change from 1 - 4  to 10 - 13 and so on for any other SVG image that will be added?

Comment: You would need to rewrite the class name in the `<style>` elements and the `class` attribute of each file.  Parsing the SVG as XML first would make that manipulation easier.

Comment: Yeah I pretty much know that this should be done. Actually asked if someone made this kind of thing before because it makes sense this would be already writtenm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone found himself due to the same issue, I didn't find an already made Python solution that rewrites the class name in the  elements and the class attribute of each path so I have created one myself:

https://github.com/Amirh24/SVGAppender

Feel free to use it :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey I was running into the exact same issue.

I found an example at https://svgutils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/publication_quality_figures.html

Try this change:

```py
import svgutils.transform as st
fig = st.SVGFigure("100px", "100px")

template = st.fromfile('firstLayer.svg')
second_svg = st.fromfile('secondLayer.svg')

fig.append([template.getroot(), second_svg.getroot()])
fig.save('merged.svg')
```